# very basic calculus doubt

Tags: calculus

Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}$. Let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$

$$ a \geq b \epsilon \implies a \geq b $$

My try: If $a < b $, then can find $n$ such that $b - a > \frac{1}{n} $. But I am stuck here. Maybe the result in not true??

if it is not true, why then is this book author assumes this in the green part??

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that $a\geq b\epsilon$ for *all* $\epsilon\in (0,1)$? The claim is certainly untrue if there is a single $\epsilon$ involved, for example $a=1,b=2,\epsilon=0.25$.

Comment: You mean $\varepsilon >1$? If $a=b$, then $a\geqslant b/2$ is false.

Comment: You must mean for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

Comment: pedro, I have edited my question with a pic

Comment: Raul; there is a difference between the statement being true for one $\epsilon$ (as stated) and for all (which your added text has).

Comment: i meant for all epsilon. Im not Raul jajjaja

Comment: Señor Ruz; you should update your question then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement should read for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

I think contradiction is easiest here.

First, if $b=0$, then it is clear there is nothing to prove.

Suppose $b>0$, and $b>a$.

Then $b= a + (b-a)$, and since $b>a$, we have $b-a >0$, and so $b-a > \frac{1}{2}(b-a) >0$.

Then $b > a + \frac{1}{2}(b-a)$, and so $b(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{b-a}{b}) > a$.

Since $\frac{1}{2}\frac{b-a}{b} \in (0,1)$, we have $1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{b-a}{b} \in (0,1)$. Hence letting $\epsilon =1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{b-a}{b} \in (0,1)$, we have $b \epsilon > a$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

It is false. Let $\epsilon=1/2$, $a=1/4$, $b=1/2$. There are many other examples.

**Added:** The question has changed, to $a\ge b\epsilon$ **for all** $\epsilon$ in the interval $(0,1)$. Then it indeed follows that $a\ge b$. For suppose to the contrary that $a\lt b$. Then $a\lt \left(\frac{a+b}{2b}\right)b$. So if we take $\epsilon= \frac{a+b}{2b}$ then $a \ge b\epsilon$ fails.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b\geq 0$ and $a\geq b\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, then $a\geq b$.

Proof:

As in copper.hat's answer, there is nothing to prove if $b=0$, so assume $b>0$.

Suppose for contradiction that $a<b$. Then $a/b<1$, so let $\epsilon$ be any number less than 1 and bigger than $a/b$. Then $b\epsilon > b(a/b)=a$, contradicting the assumption about $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a less literal interpretation of your question than some of those in the comments, this kind of argument is quite common in theoretical analysis.  The correct statement is:

**Lemma 1:** If we have positive real numbers $a$, $b$ such that for all $0 < \epsilon < 1$ we have $a \geq \epsilon b$, then $a \geq b$.

This is actually equivalent to the following more common argument:

**Lemma 2:** If we have real numbers $a$, $b$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $a \geq b - \epsilon$, then $a \geq b$.

**Proof of Lemma 2:** Suppose $a < b$; then taking $\epsilon = (b - a)/2$, we have $b - \epsilon = (a + b)/2 > 2a/2 = a$, in contradiction to the hypothesis.

To get Lemma 1, just take the logarithm:
$$a \geq \epsilon b \iff \log a \geq \log b + \log \epsilon \qquad
  a \geq b \iff \log a \geq \log b$$
Since $0 < \epsilon < 1$, we have $\log \epsilon < 0$, so Lemma 2 applies with $\epsilon$ being played by $-\log \epsilon$.

The reason this argument is so common is, roughly, that all quantities defined by limits (the central concept in analysis) can only be approached by approximation, i.e. to within a difference of $\epsilon$.  So rather than comparing two things directly we compare them to all degrees of approximation and let the error approach zero; this lemma allows the comparison to pass to the limit.